# Struggling to understand proof, there is no simple group of order $525$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Prove there is no simple group of order $525.$

$N(H)$ is the normalizer of a set $H$.

Proof:Let $L_7$ be a Sylow $7$ subgroup of $G$. It follows that $|N(L_7)|=35$ by the sylow theorems. Let $L$ be a subgroup of $N(L_7)$ of order $5$. Since $N(L_7)$ is cyclic $N(L) \geq N(L_7)$( I do not understand this part of the proof), so that $35$ divides $|N(L)|$. But L is contained in a sylow $5$ subgroup which is abelian, thus $25$ divides $|N(L)|$ as well. It follows that $175$ divides $|N(L)|$, now the index theorem gives a contradiction.

I am having a lot of confusion proving nonabelian groups of specific orders are not simple, because all of the new facts appearing about normalizers, which I have never learnt before. How should I better learn how to derive facts about normalizers.

In particular in this proof, I know why $|N(L_7)|=35$, I do not need help on that, but why does this line hold?

Let $L$ be a subgroup of order $5$. Since $N(L_7)$ is cyclic $N(L) \geq N(L_7)$ so that $N(L_7)$ is a subgroup of $N(L)$?

Comment: Let $A$ be an abelian subgroup of $G$ (which can be a general group, not necessarily one of order $525$), and let $B$ be a subgroup of $A$. Then every element of $A$ commutes with every element of $B$, whence $A \subseteq C(B) \subseteq N(B)$. And $N(L_7)$ is cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: A cyclic group has exactly one subgroup of each order dividing the group's order. So $L$ is the *unique* subgroup of $L_7$ of order $5$, hence $L$ is characteristic in $L_7$, so it's fixed by the normalizer of $L_7$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the way to start is to prove that any group of order 35 is cyclic. Then, since $N(L_7)$ is cyclic, any subgroup of $N(L_7)$ is a normal subgroup as well. From this and from the definition of the normalizer of a subgroup, you should be able to conclude that $N(L_7)$ is contained in $N(L)$.